# How can I with LiNQ select items from a list based on another list?

Tags: c#, linq

I am creating a game, and my table layout looks like this:

```
dbPlayer:
Id (int)
...

dbGame:
Id (int)
Finished (bool)
...

dbGamePlayer:
GameId
PlayerId
...
```

Given a Players ID, how can I select all games that the player is involved in, but has not (true) finished?

This is what I've go so far:

```
from g in dbGame
join gp in dbGamePlayer on gp.GameId equals g.Id
join p in dbPlayer on p.Id equals gp.PlayerId
where p.Id == 1 && g.Finished == false
select g
```

But I'm getting errors all over the place. Sorry, I'm new at LINQ

Comment: Can you give us code examples? i.e. What are you selecting from where?

Comment: A: 'You simply select all games that the player is involved in, but is not finished'. If you want more help than that you have to show us what you done so far and what is not working.

Comment: What is the error you say you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Your LINQ Statement is wrong.

The joint `object` (`gp`) has to be on the right side of the equals-Statement.

```
join gp in dbGamePlayer on g.Id equals gp.GameId
```

Same applies to the second join:

```
join p in dbPlayer on gp.PlayerId equals p.Id
```

So the full statement should look like:

```
IEnumerable query = (from g in dbGame
join gp in dbGamePlayer on g.Id equals gp.GameId 
join p in dbPlayer on gp.PlayerId equals p.Id 
where p.Id == 1 && g.Finished == false
select g);
```

But the error

> Name model is not in scope on the left side of equals.
>   Consider swapping the expression on the either side of equals.

should have told you that.